# Ubuntu Touch Desktop?

Tags: unity

Does Ubuntu Touch have a desktop mode? I mean with like a full unity inferface so you can use your tablet like a regular Ubuntu PC. Heard this is not possible due to the display server. I did however see this  a few months back and wondering if its on Touch:

http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android

Comment: I think this will work with a dockingstation. You will have do dock your tablet/phone with Ubuntu on your screen at the tablet/phone will enter a desktop mode which is available on the screen. So, it would be like Ubuntu for Android, but more like Ubuntu for Ubuntu Touch. But I also think, all this stuff is still in production and also conception. We will see, how it will work (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is a bit limited, the only 2 desktop applications that are available are LibreOffice and Gimp

Others can be installed by using a tool named Libertine
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Libertine
It  needs more documentation to be useful to novice users

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it does have a desktop mode.  At least, that's how they advertised it.  Idk how it would work though.